# Local file is out of SVN, but exists in repository

Tags: svn, repository

I have found strange thing in my project. I have a file in my SVN repository. I have it in my working copy too. But the problem is that in my working copy the file is out of SVN control! Not sure how this have happened, probably I have pressed "mark conflict resolved" in Intellij Idea without investigating whats up. *svn status* returns "?" status for it. How can I fix it?

If I run *svn update* nothing happens, because everything is up-to-date.

If I add that file to SVN locally, than it would be considered new and during my next commit I will send it to server. I dont want this.

What happened to my file and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the local file is out of SVN control I propose

1) you rename it

2) update the repository

3) compare your local file with the one in the repo

If you are very sure of the goodness of your local version then you can just overwrite the older file. If not you will need some sort of semi-automatic comparison of the files and decide how to repair conflicts, if any.

Does that make sense?